# difference on list.add() AND list.add(new ArrayList<>())?

Tags: java, list, object, arraylist

the following code:

```
List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> row = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  row.add(i);
  res.add(row);
}
```

> res: [**[1,2,3],[1,2,3]**,[1,2,3]]

wrote in this way:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  row.add(i);
  res.add(new ArrayList<>(row));
}
```

> res: [**[1],[1,2]**,[1,2,3]]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first case, you've only create 2 objects (called `new` twice).  You've added the second to the first 3 times, resulting in the second object appearing 3 times in the first.

In the second case, you've created 5 objects: `res`, a work area `row`, and 3 copies of `row` taken a 3 different moments in time.   The 3 copies are added to `res`.