# java Recursion pass by reference or value?

Tags: java, recursion, pass-by-reference, backtracking, pass-by-value

I'm trying to solve a recursion/DFS/backtracking problem, which is return all possible subsets for a num;
for example:
Input: nums = [1,2,3]
Output: [[],[1],[2],[1,2],[3],[1,3],[2,3],[1,2,3]]

So I wrote the following code:

```
class Solution {
public List<List<Integer>> subsets(int[] nums) {
    
    if (nums == null) return new ArrayList<>();
    
    List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> numlist = new ArrayList<>();
    
    dfs(nums, 0, numlist, result);
    
    return result;
    
    
}
private void dfs(int[] nums, int index, List<Integer> numlist, List<List<Integer>> set) {
    if (index == nums.length) {
        // set.add(numlist);     // ->>>>>>>>>> WRONG 
        set.add(new ArrayList<>(numlist)); // ->>>>>>>>> RIGHT 
        return;
    }
    
    // left:
    numlist.add(nums[index]);
    dfs(nums, index + 1, numlist, set);
    // backtrack:
    numlist.remove(numlist.size() - 1);  // delete the last char in the sb and backtrack
    dfs(nums, index + 1, numlist, set);
}
```

}

I am very confused that, in the line I marked as WRONG and RIGHT, why is that when I use "set.add(numlist)" the result will be all empty which is [[],[],[],[],[],[]], but when I changed it to "set.add(new ArrayList<>(numlist))", the result is correct. Why do I have to create a new value copy of the numlist to be added to the result? I thought JAVA is always pass-by-reference, so everytime it should be the value of numlist to be added to the result, and then remain unchanged, but why the the result arraylist changed if I didn't create a copy of the value?

I am very confused and thought it should be something related to reference/value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [difference on list.add() AND list.add(new ArrayList<>())?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45929473/difference-on-list-add-and-list-addnew-arraylist)

Comment: java is pass by value. the value in this case is a reference to the original list, which will also be changed, when you access it through this new reference. hope I got this right, didn't go through the details.